# Путь для написания приложения под IOS и Android

Tags: swift, kotlin, cordova

Имеется сайт, и его нужно перенести в вид приложения, сам сайт по себе, "эмулятор" тотолизатора. Для меня есть 2 пути, использование Cordova,
либо изучение Котлина и Свифта. Сроки не обозначены (но жизнь не вечна). Взаимодействие с системой телефона, это оповещение и использование камеры (для сканирование qr кода) не более того, все остальные процессы внутри приложения. Связь с сервером, для получения данных, по сокетам.
Багажник знание скуден, javascript (8 лет), php (10 лет), минимальные C# (можно не считать вообще), работа в команде уровень 0, (мама из дома не выпускает) то есть корявость кода обеспечена и понимание что хорошо, что плохо отсутствует. И в общем то, ***вопрос есть ли смысл, для такого приложения погружаться в изучение Котлина и Свифта, если да, подскажите литературу, если нет, подскажите, камни Cordova или альтернативы, благодарю.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если функционал не сложный, и вы 200% не будете его в будущем усложнять и оптимизировать, то есть смысл использовать конструктор 2 в 1. Гораздо быстрее получите результат.

Если функционал замороченный и возможны его доработка - лучше сразу использовать нативные средства разработки. Но, мне кажется, стать супергероем и в Swift и в Kotlin будет не просто, хотя все зависит от вашего желания.

По Swift для начала рекомендую https://swiftbook.ru и https://edu.academiait.ru (много бесплатных видео, но некоторые уже устарели - про Swift 3 лучше не смотреть). На youtube полно роликов тоже.
Потом - https://www.raywenderlich.com (на английском! у него, кстати, про Kotlin тоже много обучающих материалов).

Comment: Благодарю за информацию для обучения, супергероев не сущесвтует, но можно одеть костюм и прикинутся таковым) Но по сути я понял, что лучше не терять время и использовать конструктор.

Comment: Один из оптимальных вариантов: 2 друга вместе делают проект, один - iOS'ник, второй - Android'ерщик (видел такое наименование :)
Вопрос: кто написал backend? :)

Comment: Осталось завести друзей. Тогда конструктор брать, но надеюсь они не сильно багнутые. Потому что я любой баг делю на 2 и умножаю на 10

Comment: На днях общался с товарищем, который занимался iOS-разработкой в довольно крупной IT-конторе. Писал на Swift. А потом, оказывается, переключился на Flutter. Сейчас ушел в другую компанию - тоже на Flutter'e пишет.
Сейчас это модный тренд - если заказчик хочет сэкономить и получить быстро не сложный функционал.

Comment: Интересная ситуация, пойду почитаю по сабжу благодарю, прочитал, у Darta с Flutter, есть возможность еще написание под под винду, мак и линукс это еще лучше

Answer (score 0):

Если все готово и нужно упаковать - максимально легкий и выгодный вариант. Плагинов полно, для QR в том числе.

Можно глянуть в сторону PWA ещё. Возможно также с минимальными изменениями поедет.

Comment: А какие фреимворки в случае с PWA посоветуете?